# 英語版では反対票で自分の信頼度が減るが、日本語版では減らない

Tags: サポート, 投票の仕方

本家stackoverflowでは反対票を入れると自分の信頼度がマイナス1減る。
つまり、自分の身を挺してまでも反対票を入れるというイメージなのですが、
日本語版だと、自分の信頼度は減っていないようです。

何か意図があって英語版との違いがあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問に対するマイナス票では信用度は減りませんが、回答にマイナス票を入れても減らなかったのでしょうか？

Comment: ヘルプ参考：日本語版のヘルプ [信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) だと判断しにくいですが、英語版のヘルプ [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) だと明確に、回答に反対票を投じたときにのみ -1で、質問へ反対票を投じたときにはマイナスにはならないことがわかります

Comment: @holywise ヘルプの文章は確かに、反対投票したのか、されたのか、わかりにくいですね。

Comment: 失礼しました。私の勘違いでした。おっしゃる通り、回答に反対票のときに-1の動作でした。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

このままだと回答なしで終わってしまいそうなので、一応回答として体裁を整えておきます。

---

日本語版ヘルプ「[信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)」より

> **信用度は以下の場合に失います。**
>
> 質問への反対票: −2
>   回答への反対票: −2
>   回答に反対投票した: −1
>   質問にお礼を提示した: -お礼の全額
>   自分の投稿が、6 件のスパムまたは不快の通報を受けた:−100

英語版ヘルプ「[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)」より

> **You lose reputation when:**
>
> your question is voted down: −2
>   your answer is voted down: −2
>   you vote down an answer: −1
>   you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
>   one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

日本語版の表現だとわかりにくいかもしれませんが、英語版では趣旨が明確です。
つまりユーザーが能動的に反対票を投じるときのルールは次のようなものです。

- 誰かの**回答**へ反対票を投じる場合には自らの信用度を1失います
- 誰かの**質問**へ反対票を投じる場合には自らの信用度には変化はありません

この点において、英語版と日本語版には違いはないはずです。