# 文章がわかりにくい：ヘルプに書かれた、信用度が増減する場面の例

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプ記事「[信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)」の[例がわかりにくいという話](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2049/8000)を見かけたので、訳の変更を提案します。

原文： https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

以下、修正案です。

> **次のような場面で信用度を獲得します：**
>
> - 質問がプラス投票された: +5
> - 回答がプラス投票された: +10
> - 回答が「承認済み」とマークされた: +15 (承認した側にも +2)
> - 提案した編集内容が承認された: +2 (ユーザーあたり合計 +1000 まで)
> - 回答にお礼が授与された: +お礼の全額
> - 回答に自動的にお礼が授与された: お礼の額の +1/2 (参考：[お礼の仕組み](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty))
> - サイトの関連付けボーナス: +100 (各サイトで1回ずつ)
>
> （中略）
>
> **逆に、信用度を失うこともあります：**
>
> - 質問がマイナス投票された: −2
> - 回答がマイナス投票された: −2
> - 誰かの回答にマイナス投票した: −1
> - 誰かの質問にお礼を提示した: -お礼の全額
> - 自分の投稿が、スパムまたは不快として6回通報された:−100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

適用しました（holywiseの部分も追加しました）。確認よろしくお願いします。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: 「お礼の仕組み」がリンクじゃなくなっています

Comment: @unarist 指摘ありがとうございます。訂正済みです。

Answer (score 4):

概ね良いと思いますが、

> - 回答が「承認済み」とマークされた: +15 (承認した側にも +2)

は次のように項を分けてしまったほうがすっきりするように感じます。

- 回答が「承認済み」とマークされた: +15
- 回答を「承認済み」とマークした： +2